Visual assessment of scatterplots acceptable?
I have a fairly basic question about analyzing a dataset of measurements taken on a number of fish, which I’m doing as part of a student project. So I have measurements of four species of fish of which I know the species (based on DNA analysis), with about fifty individuals per group. In addition, I also have a dozen fish of unknown species. I want to explore if I the unknown individuals can be assigned to a species, based on the measurements. In fact a previous study already confirmed that this can be done. However, the unknown individuals most likely belong to multiple species. So it does not make sense to analyze them as a group together. They would therefore have to be analyzed independently as individuals and the typical tests (Student's t-test, ANOVA) done in the previous study would be difficult to apply.
So far, I only plotted the measurements on an xy-axis, to visually assess how the specimens plot in relation to the groups of known fish. However, I’ve been criticized for not having used any proper statistical tests to make the distinction. So I have two questions:

to what extent is it “wrong” to merely do a visual assessment of the data? I know that this is a simplistic way of dealing with the data, but does this necessarily make my analysis invalid? Especially, because the unknown samples can only be analyzed one at a time. To what extent is this acceptable?
What other tests would be useful?


What are the measurements?  Do you mean something like the length, width, and height of each fish?  Can you paste in the plot[s] you are asking about?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

+1.  On the face of it, your critics fail to see the role or value of exploratory data analysis, perhaps believing that all of statistics consists of hypothesis tests--yet EDA seems to be what you are engaged in.  Moreover, it is incorrect to characterize visual assessment as "simplistic:" it is only as simplistic as the assessment itself and in practice can be rich, complex, and insightful.

It certainly isn't "wrong", but there can be better and worse ways to do this.  It would help if you could answer my questions and provide some additional information.

Many thanks everyone for the answers. This is very useful. The person who assessed my results really made me feel like I was an idiot, so this is encouraging. I agree the Mahalanobis distance is a good idea.

You ask:


to what extent is it “wrong” to merely do a visual assessment of
the data? I know that this is a simplistic way of dealing with the
data, but does this necessarily make my analysis invalid? Especially,
because the unknown samples can only be analyzed one at a time. To
what extent is this acceptable?


It isn't wrong at all to do this. Thee are additional things you can do, but this is a good first step. Looking at a scatterplot matrix may help. Jginestet's idea of Mahlanobis distance may also help.
How "acceptable" it is depends on who is doing the accepting. I would find it very acceptable. People who only know a little statistics may find it unacceptable. People at this stage can sometimes get obsessed with following a particular routine. I like this quote from David Cox:

There are no routine statistical questions, only questionable
statistical routines.

You also ask


What other tests would be useful?


Maybe none. A statistical test requires a hypothesis. You are not given a hypothesis, you are asked to assign observations to groups. What would you test?
EDIT: I took out the reference to cluster analysis following the comment, which made sense.

This is not a complete answer, but it should point you in a useful direction (I do not want to write "the right", because there may be more ways to skin this fish -in this case-; but it will get the job done, because it is exactly what it was designed to do). You are basically trying to create a classifier (among the 4 fish species), and use that classifier on unknown subjects. The first thing that came to mind when I read the question is Mahalanobis distance.
Use the measurements from the the known species (~50 per group). This will give you 4 clusters of data in multivariate space. Then, for each unknown fish, compute the Mahalanobis distance between it and the 4 clusters. Then pick the shortest distance as the most likely group it should belong to. R, and other software packages, support Mahalanobis distances.
Wrt your visual assessment, there is nothing formally "wrong" with it. Indeed, your eyeballs will perform kind of a cluster analysis; they will assess how close the unknown fish is to the various known clusters. The only caveat is wrt dimensionality; if you have many measurements (length, weight, width, size of the fins, mouth/eye distance, etc... ), then visualizing them only 2 (or even 3) at a time will be insufficient, and may even be misleading. The larger the dimensionality of your multivariate space, the less a visual assessment will be informative.

Here is something more general. Usually a data analysis problem is driven by one or more specific research questions. Even if the aim is basically exploratory, meaning that you just want to get an impression "what goes on in the data" without having a specific aim from the start, one would usually take some steps that are driven by temporary questions. This is very important, as different statistical methods address different questions.
Data visualisation is pretty much always a good thing to do, because different statistical methods rely on explicit and implicit assumptions, and even though technically a certain method may address the question you are interested in, it may fail in some situations because the data don't play ball with the assumptions and you may have a misleading result. Visualisation can help to see such things. Note though that also how to exactly visualise the data will be driven by general or temporary research aims. For sure data visualisation (with suitable interpretation) is acceptable and actually part of pretty much all data analysis. But is visualisation alone acceptable?
There are certain research questions (particularly exploratory ones) that can be well addressed by data visualisation and maybe some very basic descriptive statistics alone, and I have occasionally told people whom I have given statistical advice that in their situation it may be enough to produce a suitable data visualisation that basically shows what is going on (significance tests and the like will not always add useful information). So there are situations in which I'd say, yes, data visualisation is (pretty much) enough.
Chances are we don't have all information here, but to me it looks like something more should be done for this problem. If the major task is to classify the fish with unknown species to the known species, I'd indeed be disappointed (as a reviewer, say) to have this done just by looking at a graph. Note that a problem with visual data analysis is that decisions are subjective and cannot necessarily be reproduced, so somebody else looking at the same graph would maybe assign the fish differently, with no clear rationale how to do this. So to me the problem looks like a supervised classification problem as mentioned in the answer of @jginestet, i.e., you'd want a formal rule to decide for unclassified fish to which species they belong. There is a large number of methods in the literature to do this, and I don't know how much you know of them or whether you were even expected to find out about them on your own. An additional complication may be that there is no guarantee that the unclassified fish belong to one of the four species already known, so you may also think about a "reject option", i.e., a rule that says that an unclassified fish should not be assigned to one of the four known species. It may also be of interest to say something about the uncertainty in the classification using techniques such as cross-validation.
Having done such things, you can use the plot that you have made to assess whether the classifications you got from some method seems to make sense (and also whether it seems there is a need for a "reject option" or not). Also, earlier, a plot will give you information about which of many possible classification methods may be more or less promising for this problem (in case you know several ones, that is).
Note also that much visual analysis involves loss of information, for example when looking at first Principal Components or Multidimensional Scaling. When having more than 2 variables, even looking at all 2-dimensional scatterplots will not show you all information in the data, as there may be dependence and interaction patterns that can only be assessed looking at more than two dimensions together. So making decisions from plots alone will not necessarily make optimal use of all information in the data (formal methods will not necessarily do that either though).
How much you can be expected to do obviously depends on your knowledge and the time frame of the project. However my main message here is that the starting point should be the research question, and in what way this question can be addressed. Data visualisation is pretty much always worthwhile, but very often you may want something formal, particularly because in science results are meant to be reproducible by others, and "look at the plot and see" doesn't really deliver that. Also many methods are specifically directed at specific problems and there are some that directly address yours (assuming that indeed supervised classification is the major issue here).

+1, this is basically my thinking behind my comments requesting more information.
